# How to upgrade package.json and npm-shrinkwrap.json to the latest node v8.11.1

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface, package.json, npm-shrinkwrap

I have a CLI git repository that contains list of modules of package.json and npm-shrinkwrap.json files.Currently this works fine with node v6.11.1,I want to upgrade it to support to the latest node v8.11.1.

I have tried these below commands but no help

> npm i -g npm-check-updates
>
> npm-check-updates -u
>
> npm install

Any help would be appreciated.